# How to re-import module in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm fairly new to typescript but I think this issue is actually indirectly related to Node. Anyway, I'm trying to write a small node lib and I'm using Typescript. 
I have a class, let's say:

```
    //foo.ts
    export class Foo {
        constructor(options:Options = {}) { ... }
    }
```

However using this class directly most times will not be desirable given the nature of my lib, so I'm also exporting a module

```
    //module.ts
    import { Foo } from './foo'

    let instance
    ... // other methods
    export function init(options: Options) {
        instance = new Foo(options)
    }
```

Everything works as I expect. The issue I have is to write unit tests for `module.ts`. I need to write several test cases, but once I call `module.init(options)` once, the instance will be created and as node cache modules, importing it again in my test file will still have the `foo` instance there. In vanilla javascript I used the [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to generate other instances of the module, but it seems that it doesn't work so well with typescript... How would I "force" node to "re-import" a "clean" instance of my module?

Answer (score -1):

> How would I "force" node to "re-import" a "clean" instance of my module?

A simple factory method e.g. Change

```
//foo.ts
export class Foo {
    constructor(options:Options = {}) { ... }
}
```

To:

```
//foo.ts
class Foo {
    constructor(options:Options = {}) { ... }
}
export const create(options: Options): Foo {
   return new Foo(options);
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something in your approach, but I think that doesn't solve the problem. Even if I use a factory, the foo instance would be created only once in `module.ts` and would stay there for successive imports of `module.ts`. Let's say that in some random spec file, I have to import `module.ts` and initialize the foo instance with options to test something. Then, in `module.spec.ts`, I'm testing error messages thrown if the `foo` instance was not created. Since node caches imports, the instance would already be there. I don't really want to worry about the order tests will run